# How to use jsPDF correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am a newbie trying to use jsPDF. I have a simple link that will build a pdf file and save it. However I can't get it to work. When I click the link, nothing happens. It's as if I'm not referencing the scripts. Am I missing something?

Edit: I forgot to note that I am test running this using xampp.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\devtest\jsPDF-master\libs\FileSaver.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\devtest\jsPDF-master\jspdf.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <script>
        function ci(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.setFontSize(22);
        doc.text(20, 20, 'My First PDF');
        doc.addPage();
        doc.setFontSize(16);
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is some normal sized text underneath.');
        doc.save('Test.pdf'); }
        </script>
        <a href="javascript:ci()">Click me </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: When I click the link, nothing happens. It's as if I'm not referencing the scripts. Am I missing something?

Comment: It may depend on the browser, but trying to reference all the way back to `C:\ ` will probably not work. The browser may also be interpreting it as a relative reference, i.e. `[path_to_your_page]/C:/Program Files (x86)/...`. Try moving `FileSave.js` and `jspdf.js` into the same location as your page, and referencing it as `src=FileSave.js` etc.

Comment: regardless of where you are running it, xammp or live, my answer will work, you just need to adjust the file path

Answer (score 0):

As @puddinman13 mentioned in a comment you have to reference the script files relative to the apache root. You should also use forward slashes when referencing files on the web. In your example it would be something like this:

```
<script src='devtest/jsPDF-master/libs/FileSaver.js'></script>
<script src='devtest/jsPDF-master/jspdf.js'></script>
```

It looks like you downloaded the code straight from github? In that case I would recommend that you use the dist files instead of the source files.

```
<script src='devtest/jsPDF-master/dist/jspdf.min.js'></script>
```

Also be aware of that the current (2015-09-20) 1.1 release on the master branch is a prerelease and you might want to check out 0.9 or 1.0 instead.